# Cannot add an account to VS Azure Subscriptions

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I just installed the Azure SDK for Visual Studio 2013 from this link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=324322. When I restart Visual Studio, and go to Server Explorer, I see the Azure node. I right click, and go to Manage and Filter Azure Subscriptions. I click 'Add an account...' and nothing happens.

I'm using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013, Update 5

PS. I thought maybe it was the account I had logged into Visual Studio with, so in the top right, I did Sign Out, and now I can't sign back in. I get this:

> The component 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client.Controls.BrowserWindow' does not have a resource identified by the URI '/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client;component/controls/browserwindow.xaml'.

Comment: Same issue here, when trying to update my license. It also get this when trying to logout and login again..

Comment: Confirmed, I have this issue as well.

Comment: Can you guys upvote the Connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2748603/cant-sign-in-to-visual-studio-2013-after-installing-azure-sdk

Answer (score 8):

I have the same issue but I believe I have found a workaround.

I went to the folder: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Windows Azure Tools\Common\KeychainDlls"

I renamed Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client.dll to something else (e.g. __Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client.dll)

I then restarted VS2013 and I was able to sign in.

Then finally I renamed it back.

I hope this helps

Comment: If anyone's experiencing this issue, please upvote on Microsoft Connect:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2748603/cant-sign-in-to-visual-studio-2013-after-installing-azure-sdk